# Monodevelop GUI designer does not work on ubuntu

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, designer, monodevelop

Monodevelop GUI designer does not work on ubuntu (2.4 and 2.6 beta 2). When I tried to drag controls/containers from the toolbox, It is doing nothing. I couldnt' drag controls in the form window.

Comment: What is the version ? All dependiences are installed correctly ? Have you installed from repository ?

Comment: monodevelop 2.6 beta 2, ubuntu 11.04

Comment: no, monodevelop installed from sources

Comment: Did you make sure that the first thing you dragged onto the form was a container?

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step:

**Prerequisites**

- Installed monodevelop version from the distro repos 
  (convers major dependencies)
- Extra dependencies:
  autoconf
  automake
  intltool

**Install using latest source from github**

```
$ git clone git://github.com/mono/monodevelop.git -b 3.0-series
$ cd monodevelop
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Run (also can add shortcut to applications menu)
/usr/local/bin/monodevelop.

This worked for me on xubuntu 12.04 with no errors.